# How do we build Normalized text file from DeNormalized one?

Tags: java, text, sh, normalize, denormalized

Thanks for your replies/time.

We need to build a **Normalized text file** from **DeNormalized text file**. We explored couple of options such as unix shell , and Loading into data base etc. I am looking pick up better ideas for resolutions from this community.

The input text file is various length with comma delimited records. The content may look like this:

```
**XXXXXXXXXX , YYYYYYYYYY, TTTTTTTTTTT, UUUUUUUUUU, RRRRRRRRR,JJJJJJJJJ
111111111111,   22222222222, 333333333333, 44444444, 5555555, 666666
EEEEEEEE,WWWWWW,QQQQQQQ,PPPPPPPP**
```

We like to normalize as follows:

```
**XXXXXXXXXX , YYYYYYYYYY
TTTTTTTTTTT, UUUUUUUUUU
RRRRRRRRR,JJJJJJJJJ
111111111111,   22222222222
333333333333, 44444444
5555555, 666666
EEEEEEEE,WWWWWW
QQQQQQQ,PPPPPPPP**
```

Are there any simple approach to get the above?

Thanks in helping.

Comment: read each line, split by , output pairs, cross your fingers and hope you don't get an odd number of oojahs in a line

Comment: are the **s just a failed attempt at formatting by you, or are they actually in the file?

Comment: **s are not part of the file. I tried to make it BOLD, so it appended ** in the beginning and end.

Comment: Split by and output pairs are part of what scripting? Do you have sample script?

Comment: Thanks Tony, Robin. It is good to know about you.

Comment: Seems to have been re-posted in somewhat edited for here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20445701/398670