# How do we build Normalized table from DeNormalized text file one?

Tags: linux, postgresql, sed, awk, greenplum

**How do we build Normalized table from DeNormalized  text file one?**

Thanks for your replies/time.

We need to build a Normalized DB Table from DeNormalized text file. We explored couple of options such as unix shell , and PostgreSQL etc. I am looking learn better ideas for resolutions from this community.

The input text file is various length with comma delimited records. The content may look like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXX , YYYYYYYYYY, TTTTTTTTTTT, UUUUUUUUUU, RRRRRRRRR,JJJJJJJJJ
111111111111,   22222222222, 333333333333, 44444444, 5555555, 666666
EEEEEEEE,WWWWWW,QQQQQQQ,PPPPPPPP
```

We like to normalize as follows (Split & Pair):

```
XXXXXXXXXX , YYYYYYYYYY
TTTTTTTTTTT, UUUUUUUUUU
RRRRRRRRR,JJJJJJJJJ
111111111111,   22222222222
333333333333, 44444444
5555555, 666666
EEEEEEEE,WWWWWW
QQQQQQQ,PPPPPPPP
```

**Do we need to go with text pre-process and Load approach?**

**If yes, what is the best way to pre-process?**

**Are there any single SQL/Function approach to get the above?**

Thanks in helping.

Comment: Appears to be an edited version of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20433479/398670

Answer (score 4):

Using `gnu awk` (due to the RS)

```
awk '{$1=$1} NR%2==1 {printf "%s,",$0} NR%2==0' RS="[,\n]" file
XXXXXXXXXX,YYYYYYYYYY
TTTTTTTTTTT,UUUUUUUUUU
RRRRRRRRR,JJJJJJJJJ
111111111111,22222222222
333333333333,44444444
5555555,666666
EEEEEEEE,WWWWWW
QQQQQQQ,PPPPPPPP
```

`{$1=$1}` Cleans up and remove extra spaces
`NR%2==1 {printf "%s,",$0}` prints odd parts
`NR%2==0` prints even part and new line
`RS="[,\n]"` sets the record to `,` or newline

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried. It works. **Will RS =.. put  ^M for some records at the end?** I have the same format with lot of trailing commas at the end of each records.  Like 'XXXXXXXXXX , YYYYYYYYYY, TTTTTTTTTTT, UUUUUUUUUU, RRRRRRRRR,JJJJJJJJJ,,,,,,,,,,,,'                                 How do I process this file using your awk command?

Comment: It will not add `^M`.  You can just test for `$0` to not get the extra commas like this: `awk '{$1=$1} NR%2==1 && $0 {printf "%s,",$0} NR%2==0 && $0' RS="[,\n]" file`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update. Here is what I did in Linux server.

```
    sed -i 's/\,,//g' inputfile   <------ Clean up lot of trailing commas

    awk '{$1=$1} NR%2==1 {printf "%s,",$0} NR%2==0' RS="[,\n]" inputfile <----Jotne's idea

    dos2unix -q -n inputfile outputfle <------ to remove ^M in some records

    outputfile is ready to process as comma delimited format
```

Any thoughts to improve above steps further?

Thanks in helping.